# C# Simple web server with url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, url-parameters

I am trying to create little program which is going to act like a web server and accepts url parameters. I have found this example project: https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx

Is there any way to make this receive my url parameters? Is there any other example project like this which has this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at OWIN/Katana.
Based on your question – and with OWIN's ability to be hosted in any process – this might fit quite well and is the current way to go:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana

You'll find tons of sample on this topic. For your question related to parameters you could refer to [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api).

Based on the first link you could do something like the follwing:

```
public class Startup1
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            var value = context.Request.Query.Get("someKey");

            if (value == "foo")
            {
                // do something
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello, world.");
        });
    }
}
```

A request could look like this: `http://someServer:80/?someKey=foo`

Comment: Well, this OWIN / Katana project looks promising. I can confirm that what @Shahrooz linked in the other answer works, and I am sure this one does as well. But I am not closer to get those parameters. Could you please be more 'specific'?

Comment: See my updated answer. Further research is up to you ;)

Answer (score 4):

Please read this article:
[Building A Simple File Server With OWIN and Katana](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx)

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "http://localhost:8080";
            WebApp.Start(url, builder => builder.UseFileServer(enableDirectoryBrowsing:true));            
            Console.WriteLine("Listening at " + url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific on how to implement this into my app?

Comment: @Zoszko you can go to this article: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on your project example try to put in method SendRequest as follow:

```
string name = request.QueryString.Get("name");
            switch (name){
                case "a":
                    return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page a.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
                    break;
                case "b":
                    return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page b.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
                    break;
                default:
                    return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page .<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
                    break;
            }
```